# Create .gitignore, .trivyignore, .dockerignore once per multiple git repositories

Tags: git, microservices, gitignore, dockerignore

We have a microservices project (tens of microservices) which are spread across different repositories instead of a single large mono-repo. Each of the repositories has files like `CODEOWNERS`, `.gitignore`, `.dockerignore` etc.

Most of the times when we need to change those files we need to make a similar change and we create a bunch of the PRs, which is annoying and time consuming.

Is there a way to define those files once per multiple repositories so we can change them in one place?

[image]

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: You could implement a bot which periodically checks out the repos, compares those files to a template repo, and opens the PRs for you.  I'm not aware of an existing bot that does that, but it would be along the lines of dependabot, scala-steward, and other automatic dependency upgrade bots.

Comment: It's also worth noting that part of the point of microservices is that each service only changes when it needs to; if a .gitignore or .dockerignore change doesn't actually ignore any files, why should that change be applied?

Comment: Yes, some of the files like .gitignore are "set once and forget", but other files (for example .trivyignore) are usually changes a bit more often. I was thinking about the same thing as you've suggested with a bot (and github actions) but just was wondering if there is a better way to do that.